# magento 2 id numbering reassignment

Tags: magento2

TLDR, Each of the new items created gets an ID # assigned, over the time of item being deleted remade and or just many added, the new ids are in the thousands with many unused Numbers in between.

Is there a way for the id to be re-assigned, to have those holes filled, and the ID values return to a lower number?

My boss fears errors manifesting in the long run if it is allowed to just run wild.  I do not foresee this happening, but I am also brand new to working on Magento2.

Google has been a let-down so far with no one bringing the issue anywhere I looked, I am nearly convinced it is a non issue due to this, but a part of me cannot shake the though that could have worded this wrong and just made a mistake.

Comment: check out the data type on the database for those IDs, then check out the max number for that data type in the database, you should have **plenty** of room, it is a non-issue